# Good Quality Breadboards?

Tags: breadboard

Between my engineering classes and out-of-class projects, I'm always having to clear my breadboard every time I attempt a project. I would like to invest in some good, quality breadboards to conduct out-of-class projects on. Therefore, I have a couple questions I would like your expertise on.

I've always favored the more general layout, without the terminals that can be added to the breadboard. I don't always need these with little projects I'm doing, like Arduino projects. From what I've experienced, smaller boards that I can manipulate (move around) are always nice to have. Also, boards that are very long give me the option to utilize more components. From your expertise/experience, what type would you recommend for small projects, and would you lean more towards the longer or wider boards or towards the small ones?

I know it's dependent on the type of project; however, any suggestions/guidance is appreciated in understanding the ups and downs of each.

Comment: It appears that the question is about shopping recommendation ("Trusted Sites") and about the breadboard features and layout. This forum doesn't appreciate shopping questions. I would edit the post to remove invitation for recommendations on trustful sites.

Answer (score 26):

Ignoring the shopping recommendation portion of the question...

This is how breadboards work out best for my particular uses:

- A few long breadboards with the power strips along the sides (830 tie-points), such as the MB-102:
  [image: MB102]
- A larger number of the tiny 170 tie-point breadboards like the SYB-170, in assorted colors:
  [image: SYB-170]
  Each color denotes for me a **type of circuit**, such as "*temporary experiment*", "*near-permanent building block*", "*diagnostic tool*", or "*WHY WON'T THIS WORK?*".
- In addition, a couple of breadboard power supplies, jumper-selected 3.3 Volts and 5 Volts, the type that fit right into the power rails of the MB-102:
  [image: Breadboard power supply]
  I usually power these from 9 volt batteries for portability, or from a 12 Volt bench supply.
- A couple of the little adjustable buck regulator boards with voltage / current display:
  [image: Buck Regulator with Display]
- A few really tiny (0.36" high) **3-wire** voltmeter and ammeter LED display units:
  [image: Voltmeter]

I usually buy each of these off eBay, solely from vendors who offer free international shipping, and at prices of typically just $1 to a few dollars each. That way I can choose to dedicate any of these breadboarding blocks to a given design for extended periods, while I focus on other circuits.

---

**My approach:**

My primary circuit or project goes onto one of the big breadboards, while problematic blocks, or new stuff I am trying, go into separate logical blocks mapped to separate little breadboards.

Voltage and / or current monitoring displays get dedicated to respective breadboards, so anything going awry is quickly noticed.

Sub-circuits I use often, such as a level translator, a voltage rail splitter, a small analog joystick used as two variable voltage dividers for quick tests, and a variable current regulator, are always at hand on one specific color of the little breadboards, until I get around to putting them onto PCBs.

The buck regulators I use have adjustable current limit as well as voltage adjustment, so each can be used for specific parts (the little breadboard logical blocks) where I foresee trouble.

This works especially well for me because at any time, I am engaged in up to a dozen different projects, from pure speculative experimentation, to troubleshooting a client's product.

Overall, cost and flexibility are key parameters, while building block longevity isn't, really: I doubt I'll be wanting to use the same solderless breadboard a year or two after I bought it - surely I'll have retired each with some circuit on them, before that. Reorder costs are of little worry at the prices involved.

---

While this approach may not precisely match your way of working, I hope this answer provides some thought points to extend upon.

Comment: +1 almost exactly what I would have wanted to say. "Quality" breadboards is sort of a non-issue. I've dealt with some that seem more difficult to insert components and wires into, but generally tie points always work and they're functional.

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't seen those power supply boards before... eBay here I come.

Comment: Despite the rule that shopping questions are off-topic, the recommendation to shop for these on eBay was the most useful part of this answer. Sparkfun, Digikey, Adafruit, Radio Shack, etc. all charge $7+ for a standard breadboard, where I can get one for $3 on eBay.

Comment: Great little power supplies.

Comment: Yes, @Rocketmagnet, aren't they really cool?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have enough large and high-quality breadboard in the very beginning -- even though s/he is planning to keep things small. The thing is that you may need to create your own 5-12 converter that is the size of your small breadboard, not funny -- things I had to do when I started and then I had to wait long time for a better breadboard and/or waste time with components and hacks to somehow finish the project even though I did not have any space anymore -- it was irritating to get short circuit when things were very tightly connected. Then again it was fun to get things to smaller space!

[image]

I have small breadboards, middle-size breadboards and one higher quality breadboard *"Solderless Breadboard Protoboard 4 Bus Test Circuit Board Tie-point 1660 ZY-204"*. Lower quality breadboards can be pretty irritating with too tight holes, too little lines or poor usability. I rather buy a higher quality breadboard than get short circuits that can damage your components with EOS. It is a bit overkill to require a hobbyist to design his/her own EOS/ESD protection circuit -- although this is actually pretty funny thing and not bad idea to begin with! The cheapest higher quality breadboard I could find from eBay is Tie-point 1660 for about 10EUR.

I recommend to get breadboards of different sizes. I rather work more efficiently than waste time with poor equipments.

**Perhaps useful to the readers**

> 1. [EOS versus ESD -thread by TI](http://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/precision_amplifiers/w/design_notes/2189.electrical-over-stress-and-electrostatic-discharge-protection-of-ics.aspx) or more generally [Why do 0.02A fuses not protect a person? Why no protection from shocks?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66538/why-do-0-02a-fuses-not-protect-a-person-why-no-protection-from-shocks)